# How would I know git option's current value?

Tags: git, configuration

Sure thing, there is `git config some.option` thing. But it doesn't display default value, if it wasn't changed in any of the config files. That is, first you run `git config some.option` and then occasionally read the `git help config` to find out what the current value is. Also it seems like nobody cares. Am I possibly doing it wrong?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean.  `git config --get` or `git config --get-all` shows how they are set.  If you mean, e.g., how to interpret an *unset* value (such as for `push.default`), it's true that this is a bit of an issue: if `push.default` is unset, it means `matching` now, but will mean `simple` in the future.  As far as I know the only way to choose which one it means is to look at `git --version`.

Comment: @torek The second assumption. But it's not about `push.default` only. For example, `git config --list` doesn't show `core.pager` value, neither does `git config core.pager`. Because it's not in system, global or repository config files. One could put it this way: "How do I make `git config --list` show all the options' values, not just those in config files?"

Comment: Yes, I was just using `push.default` as an example.  As far as I know there's no way to get git to tell you what it will use if something is unset.  In fact, each git sub-command has to supply its own default value, there's no "master list".  Many git commands are shell scripts that do something like `xyz=$(git config --get foo.bar) || xyz=default_value`, so that the default is simply hard-coded in the script.  No other git command uses `foo.bar` so this works great, except when you want to know: what is the default for `foo.bar`?  Then you have to find the one command that *has* it.

Comment: This question is still a little unclear, if you still want someone to answer it, I would suggest that you try to clarify what it is that you're trying to find.

Comment: @Cupcake What exactly is unclear? Git doesn't display default values of options, that is values that are not present in system, global or repository config files. Come to think of it. `torek` clarified what's going on just fine to me. If he will turn his comment into an answer I'll accept it.